# Interest Selections on logging in: AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am making an application with `AngularJS` `HTML` `CSS` etc. I wanted help with a part that I am trying to make. What I am trying to achieve is when a user comes and logs in for the first time then he/she should be able to select some interests they have, like food, music genres, what kind of job just like netflix and spotify on first login. I want mine to be preset questiosn, for example lets say I have food, job and music at the time of login, and user click on food, then he can see some cusinies and can select them and I can store them, similarly with lets say job, I can give two options, tech or business management or anything else and people can select al these according to their interests and I can store all of it. I started simple to getting just food as an option but i can't seem to make it. Can we do it with AngularJS
?

Comment: Please can you share the code you have tried so far so that folk know what you are getting stuck on.

Comment: The problem you're facing is part server-side and part client-side. Your server must maintain a status whether or not the current user has logged in for the first time. If the server responds yes, then your client will know what view to show. As long as the server provides this information, what you're trying to do is definitely achievable in AngularJS (or any other client-side framework for that matter)